# Multiple Object With Same Value in K-Means

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

Well i have problem with my data

This is my healthcare database

(Name, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4)

Jhon   10, 20, 30, 40

Jhon    9, 12, 21, 33

Noah    8, 22, 18, 10

Anna    9, 19, 29, 32

Clark    11, 4, 17, 20

In healthcare database one person can ill two times, three times or more as you can see the example of my database there is two jhon's who have two records because he ill twice

The purpose i use k-means is to get two cluster (cluster 1 : group 1, cluster 2 : group 2) with their member

And i want get output like this :

Group 1 : jhon, clark

Group 2 : noah, anna, jhon

You see there is two jhon's, one member can be to group 1 and group 2, so how i can fix this problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means works by iterations between pairs of steps. You basically alternate between

1. assuming you know the mapping of instances to clusters, and calculate the cluster centers
2. assuming you know the cluster centers, assign instances to clusters

Thus if you have constraints, e.g., that all jhon (sic) should belong to the same cluster, you can incorporate this into step 2: you'll need to find the cluster for which the simultaneous assignment of all of them is the most likely.

See [Constrained k-means clustering with background](http://nichol.as/papers/Wagstaff/Constrained%20k-means%20clustering%20with%20background.pdf) for details.

Comment: Mr. Ami i see in section 3.1 there is step by step COP-Kmeans in step two it says `For each point di in D, assign it to the closest cluster Cj such that violate-constraints` Is this what you mean `you'll need to find the cluster for which the simultaneous assignment of all of them is the most likely` ?

Comment: but i still dont understand what is `violate-constraints(di, Cj , Con=,
Con!=)` is that algorithm or else ?